# How to Convert jbuilder(jpx) project to eclipse new project

Tags: java, spring, jbuilder

we have a jbuilder project which supports java 5. Need to convert this to latest version. Like to change the IDE to Eclipse too.

The code is working in ongoing project need to reuse the same. Plz help on this

Answer (score 1):

in this form I'm afraid community won't be able to help much, SO is intended for asking very precise questions to get precise answers. That's why you've got a downvote I believe. Welcome to the SO though.

Anyway, JBuilder is somewhat old (very old) so If you really think about updating the system, I suggest starting with building a build script in something like maven or maybe gradle.

If you go with maven, for example, you'll have a file `pom.xml` (or maybe many files if its a multi-module project) that describes a build process. Then it's possible to take advantage of eclipse maven integration and just open a pom.xml as a project (it will work in IntelliJ as well).